# Finding the efficiency class of Insertion Sort using backwards substitution

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I'm studying for a test and practicing finding the closed form of a recurrence formula using backwards substitution.

```
T(1) = 1                //this is the base case
T(n) = T(n - 1) + n     //this is the recursive step
```

So far I got this:

```
T(n) = T(n - 1) + n     // i = 1
[T(n - 2) + n-1]+n      // i = 2
T(n - 2) + 2n-1         // i = 2 (simplified)
[T(n - 3) + n-2]+2n -1  // i = 3
T(n - 3) + 3n-3         // i = 3 (simplified)

T(n - i ) + in-i        // ith substitution (pattern)
```

The next step is determining the value of i that results in the base case. For that I got:

```
T(n – i) + in-i     // ith substitution
n + in = 2i         // trying to isolate i
i = - n/(n-2)       // gives us base case (not sure if this is right)
```

Here is the part where I just feel like everything is wrong. I need to replace i with the value that gives me the base case in order to determine the efficiency class. That would mean I'd take this formula I found earlier **(T(n - i ) + in-i)** and insert the i value I just found **(i = - n/(n-2))**. It just seems like I went really wrong somewhere.

Comment: Actually I might have found where I went wrong. I think I shouldn't have simplified because the pattern of the terms would be (n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1) + n... So I'm guessing it's a summation that I use here.

Comment: If you'd carried on one more step, you'd have found that $T(n) = T(n-4) + 4n - 6$, which breaks the pattern you thought you'd seen. In fact $T(n) = T(n-i) + in + T(i-1)$, which isn't very helpful. It's probably easier in this kind of example to work upwards rather than downwards: then you'll see that $T(n) = 1 + 2  + 3 + \ldots + n$. Do you know how to take it from there?

Comment: Yes I think I do know what to do now! Thank you very much--that is a good point to keep in mind in the future that when I'm stuck and feel like it's going wrong, I should try a few more steps to see if the pattern still works. Thanks again!